# Complete action before starting next action

Tags: jquery

I have the following which doesn't work

```
$('#select').val( jQuery.url.param("id") );
$('#button').click();
```

It seems that the click executes before the line above it finishes.  How do I ensure that the first line is finished before the click gets executed?

As the click action depends of the value in the select control being set.  I am currently getting results based on the first option in the select control.

Comment: proof? if this was the case, jquery would provide callback for val(). but val() is not asynchronous function and there is something other that's wrong with your code

Comment: Don't know how to give proof as it's too much to copy and paste here.  All I can say is that the click works if the button is clicked manually as the page has fully loaded and selected the correct option in the select control.

Comment: agree with Darhazer... you should try to check with firebug or some other browser developer tools what `jQuery.url.param("id")` returns and if jQuery could find the element `#select`... i dont think the problem is what you think it is

Comment: Put the above code in a `document.ready` handler.  It's probably just that the #select element doesn't exist when you run the code, but it does when you click the button.

Comment: The click is being triggered, but it needs to wait for the first line to finish.  No point clicking if the option is not set.  At the moment it keeps getting the first option.  However, if I manually click the button later, it works fine.

Comment: What happens when you just go `$('#select').val('foo');`

Comment: @m90, it selects the correct option in the select control.

Comment: I know the click is being triggered.  The problem is that you are trying to assign a value to #select when it doesn't exist.  Put both those lines of code in a `document.ready` block to make sure it runs *after* the #select element is on the page.

Comment: @everyone, is my answer is irrelevant or have I misunderstood the question if so please can you make me correct.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is single threaded. Since none of the code above seems to have any side effects (like starting AJAX requests), the second command is executed after the first. This means something else must be wrong.

Try this:

- Do you see any errors in the error console?
- Did you check that `$('#select')` actually matches something? `$('#foo').val(...);` will not cause an error but do nothing instead.
- What happens when you step through the code in your debugger?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to execute the $('#button').click() after select's value have changed then you may try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mySelect').change(function(e){
        //alert($(this).val());
        $('#button').click();
    });

    $('#button').click(function(e){
        alert($('#mySelect').val());
    });

   // Change the value of select after 2 seconds of page load and fire the change event
   setTimeout(function(){
       $('#mySelect').val($('#mySelect option:eq(1)').val()); // Selects second item 
       $('#mySelect').change();
   }, 2000);

});
```

A fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xsMQE/4/). This may not exactly what you want but an idea.

Comment: That's not at all what he's asking.

Comment: Please tell me what does he want if I missed anything.

Comment: He's saying that he has those 2 lines of code, but the value is not getting set for #select before the button is clicked.  He's saying that they're executing the wrong way round.  He's not asking for the  button to be clicked when the value changes.

Comment: Please look at his question where he said "It seems that the click executes before the line above it finishes. How do I ensure that the first line is finished before the click gets executed?

As the click action depends of the value in the select control being set. I am currently getting results based on the first option in the select control." Also I've provided the code in my answer how to change the value and at last I mentioned "This may not exactly what you want but an idea".

Comment: Exactly - you've misunderstood "How do I ensure that the first line is finished before the click gets executed?"  Read the rest of the comments about it for further clarification.